# Why doesn't shared_ptr<A> implicit convert to shared_ptr<A const>?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, const-correctness

I tried to introduce some `const` correctness (actually functional paradigms) to some new code and found that I cannot pass an `std::shared_ptr<A>` to a function that expects an `std::shared_ptr<A const>`. Note that I don't want to cast *away* constness but introduce it, which is legal with raw pointers.

Is there some way to get around this? I didn't find a member-function to do this.

---

The precise error uttered by g++ 4.6.1 is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::shared_ptr<A>)’
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T> std::shared_ptr<_Tp> foo(std::shared_ptr<const _Tp>)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem in your case is not with the possible conversions from/to different `std::shared_ptr`, but is more related to how type inference works for template functions.

When the compiler tries to match a function call with a template, it will only accept **exact** matches, i.e. no type conversions at all. In this case, your function takes a `std::shared_ptr<const T>`, and the caller has a `std::shared_ptr<U>` where `U` is not `const`. Because the match is not **exact**, it will discard the template and pick the next overload candidate.

The simple workarounds are: avoid type inference altogether and provide the template argument:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p;
foo<A>(p);             // will use the templated shared_ptr conversion
```

Or perform the conversion yourself:

```
foo(std::shared_ptr<const A>(p));
```

Comment: `std::static_pointer_cast<int const>(p)` is another way to explicitly make a conversion.

Comment: @Xeo Because we're not removing cv-qualifiers.

Comment: @David, does `foo(std::shared_ptr<const A>(p));` preserve the reference count?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Didn't think about template resolution.

Comment: @LucDanton: But we're modifying cv-qualifiers. That's the job of `const_cast`.

Comment: @bitmask No. `const_cast` is for *removing* qualifiers. Adding them only take an implicit conversion -- `static_cast` is the appropriate cast to document a conversion as explicit. If for whatever reason during a change in code the target and source types are changed such that the source type is cv-qualified, but the target type isn't, then a `const_cast` wouldn't warn.

Comment: @MarkIngram: *preserve* in some way. Since you are creating a *copy* of the shared pointer, the value will be incremented to keep consistency. `std::shared_ptr` has support for different types of aliasing, including holding shared pointers into members of an object managed by a shared pointer, where both the pointer and the pointer to the member variable will share a count and deleter (i.e. the last one to go will cleanup)

Comment: @LucDanton: Given that the type will have to be explicitly named at least once, I find `foo<int>(p)` a bit cleaner (and shorter) than `foo(std::static_pointer<int const>(p))`, and that in turn better than `foo( std::static_pointer_cast<int const>(p) )`. If not for any other reason, there is less typing and less characters to read.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks, yes I missed the typo there, I shouldn't have said "preserve".